# Reboot Script / boot device

Tags: boot, batch-file, script

Is it possible to write a script to force a pc to reboot to the boot device selection mode? I did some research into this and always come up with ways to either boot a pc into the device selection screen, I.E. press F8, or a script to just force the PC to reboot at certain points based on certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

No, the process of booting will stop the program trying to implement the interrupts generated via the keyboard hardware while pressing a key.

Comment: Not true in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 running on UEFI can boot into the UEFI menu either by a custom action or through a command.

If you hold shift while pressing restart, you will restart to the UEFI menu.

The Windows 10 shutdown command also has a switch to do this:

```
shutdown /fw
```

This command will reboot to the userinterface of the firmware.

From this menu, you can go into the device selection mode, but you will have to make the choice yourself.

This was implemented in case the startup goes so fast that you don't even get a chance to press F8, or if you just don't want the hastle of having to press F8 during a short window at boot.